# TypeError <lambda> missing 1 required positonal argument

Tags: python, function, recursion, lambda, arguments

For school I have to finish some exercises. I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError <lambda> () missing 1 required positional argument: 'f2'
```

and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. This code is supposed to do multiple things, namely:

1. Function `OR` takes two functions as inputs and returns a `lambda` which, given one input, applies both functions to such input and computes the 'or' of the results.
2. Function `OR` takes two functions as inputs and returns a `lambda` which, given one input, applies both functions to such input and computes the 'or' of the results.
3. Function `OR` takes two functions as inputs and returns a `lambda` which, given one input, applies both functions to such input and concatenates the results.
4. `f1` is a `lambda` that checks if the input is odd.
5. `f2` is a `lambda` that checks if the input is positive.
6. `surround` is a `lambda` which given a number, returns a string made by that number surrounded by square brackets.
7. `toStar` is a `lambda` which given any input returns the string `'*'`.

This is my code:

```
def OR(f2, f1):
   return lambda f1, f2 : True if (f1 or f2) else False

def AND(f1, f2):
   return lambda  f1, f2 : True if f1 and f2 else False

def CONCAT(f, g):
  return lambda f, g : f + g

f1 = lambda f1: False if f1 % 2 == 0 else True
f2 = lambda f2: True if f2 > 0 else False
surround = lambda c : '[' + str(c) + ']'
toStar = lambda c : str(c) + '*'

a = 7
b = 9
c = 5
res1 = OR(f1, f2)(a)
res1b = AND(f1, f2)(a)
res2 = OR(f1, f2)(b)
res2b = AND(f1, f2)(b)
res3 = CONCAT(surround, toStar)(c)
res4 = CONCAT(toStar, surround)(c)
print()
```

Does anybody have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't calling `f1` or `f2` in any of the closures, and a `function` object itself is always truthy.

Comment: You description of the code makes little sense because you have "Function `OR`" repeated exactly the same way three times. Also pPlease see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OR` and `AND` should return a function of *one* argument, which calls both of its wrapped functions on that argument:

```
def OR(f1, f2):
    return lambda x: True if f1(x) or f2(x) else False
```

which can be simplified, if `f1` and `f2` are guaranteed to be predicates, to

```
def OR(f1, f2):
    return lambda x: f1(x) or f2(x)
```

`CONCAT`, similar, needs to call its wrapped functions:

```
def CONCAT(f1, f2):
    return lambda x: f1(x) + f2(x)
```

(The caller of `CONCAT` is responsible for ensuring that the return values of `f1` and `f2` are, in fact, valid operands to `+`.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out so quickly. I changed the code according to your answer and it now works how it should.